# Confused on if-statement inside for loop

Tags: for-loop, if-statement

I’m new to coding and hoping someone can shed some light on this for me. I understand how the for loop works (I think). 
My question is about this If statement. I’m just confused at the condition inside the If statement. How can the condition “someNums[b] > someNums[b+1]” ever evaluate to be true if someNums[b+1] is always 1 more than someNums[b]?

Just a little lost I guess, so any help would be much appreciated!! Also, this code is in relation to bubble sorting.

```
for(b = 0; b < someNums.length - 1 ; ++b)
{
  if(someNums[b] > someNums[b + 1])
  {
    temp = someNums[b];
    someNums[b] = someNums[b + 1];
    someNums[b + 1] = temp;
  }
}
```

Comment: `someNums[b]` and `someNums[b+1]` both represent two different numbers, b and b+1 are just offsets to memory where these numbers are stored and don't have any effect on `if` condition evaluation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

someNums here is the array maybe like [5,4,3,2,1] and what you are doing is fine that you compare the numbers at index 0 and 1, if someNums[0] >someNums[1] then you are swapping both the numbers. Do not confuse someNums[0] with some smaller value than someNums[1], they actually tell about the position of value in the array.

Comment: Ah, I just had a eureka moment. I forgot that inside the square brackets they would be referring to the position in the array, not the value, right?

Answer (score 0):

`someNums[b+1]` is not 1 greater than `someNums[b]`. The index is 1 greater, but (for example) in the case of
`someNums = [1,2,3,1], b = 2`, `someNums[b]` is 3 and `someNums[b+1]` is 1.

Answer (score 0):

I assume someNums is an array. 
In that case, the characters inside the [] refer to the nth element of said array. 
For example:

```
int someNumbs[4] = {3, 8, 5, 1};

printf("%d", someNumbs[2]);
printf("\n\n--------");

return 0;
```

This will display '5'. 
As you can see, the value of the 3rd element is larger than the 4th, although the latter have the larger index.

Answer (score 0):

You need to think at `someNums` as a recipient, let's say a a drawer chest, where you have drawers.

Every drawer is called by his index, but starting from zero instead of 1 (so `someNums[2]` is the **third** drawer).

Every drawer have something in...
So, comparing `someNums[b]` and `someNums[b+1]`, you are checking the things inside two adjacent drawers [: